# virtualbox: customize hard disk file location

Tags: virtualbox

When creating a new vm with Virtualbox, can I decide where the virtual hard drive file is located? By default, it's under $HOME/.Virtualbox but I don't want to store 8G file under my home directory, especially it's on an SSD. Is there a way to specify where the VDI file is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can select the location before saving the vdi. Click on the explorer ([image]) icon in create screen to set a location.

[image]